# Does Halal certification fund terrorism?

Tags: islam, terrorism, australia, france

Australia's One Nation political party [claims Halal certification funds terrorism](http://www.onenation.com.au/policies/halal-certification):

> Do you realise that you are paying a tax/surcharge that funds ISLAMIC SCHOOLS AND MOSQUES, when you do your shopping? What is also believed is that it funds terrorism.
>
> ...
>
> This tax is an impost on the Australian consumer, of which 98% are non-Muslim. Australians are struggling to meet every day cost of living and should not be forced to pay extra. Another great concern is, that some of the monies indirectly supports terrorism. 60% of Halal food in France is controlled by an organisation belonging to the Muslim Brotherhood. Other taxes collected go to Islamic schools and mosques or directly in to the pockets of those who see this as a viable profit making business.

Is there any evidence that Halal certification in Australia, France, or any other country has funded terrorism?

Comment: *indirectly supports terrorism* is a very broad claim.  If a charity funds refugee camps in Turkey, and later some terrorist is found to have spend time there and benefited from this charity, is that an indirect support of terrorism?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An report by the Australian Senate Standing Committees on Economics in 2015 titled "Third party certification of food" found this allegation to be untrue since there was no evidence of halal certification fees being directly related to terrorism funding.

> There have been various public claims that fees from certifying halal food
>   may be funding terrorism. AUSTRAC has no information that indicates
>   halal certification is linked to terrorism. AUSTRAC receives financial
>   transaction reports from businesses providing designated services under our
>   act. AUSTRAC monitoring of reported financial transactions allows
>   analysts to make judgements about potential risks of terrorism financing or
>   money laundering and refers relevant information to investigating agencies.
>   AUSTRAC monitors reported financial transactions, including reports of
>   suspicious financial activity and related transactions to identify money
>   movements associated with halal certification. **Of the information identified
>   from this monitoring of reported financial transactions, none of these have
>   been assessed as being related to the funding of terrorism, with regard to
>   halal certification fees.** AUSTRAC will continue to monitor reported
>   financial transactions and analyse data related to halal certification to
>   identify information that may be relevant to investigating agencies. [Source: Third party certification of food](http://www.aph.gov.au/Parliamentary_Business/Committees/Senate/Economics/Food_Cert_Schemes/Report).

Also a fact check by Australian Broadcasting Corporation found no evidence for directly linking terrorism and halal certification funds.

> While the proceeds of halal certification do fund Islamic organisations, **Fact Check could find no evidence that this money has ever flowed to terrorist groups.** [Source: Fact check: Does halal certification fund terrorism?](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2015-04-14/fact-check-does-halal-certification-fund-terrorism/6383238)